# Use new derived column value in another columns in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a query having many joins in it, and there is a situation that i have to use a CASE result value in another calculated columns. But i don't want to use any nested query is there anything that can fulfil this?

Maybe i can explain better by using below query 
Ex:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN extras.is_doubled THEN 2 
        WHEN extras.is_normal 1 
        ELSE 0.5 
    END as multiplier, 
    life x multiplier, 
    score x multiplier
FROM 
    table 
inner join 
    ... 
inner join 
    ...
inner join
```

Comment: You either have to use a nested query or repeat the `CASE` statement.

Comment: Repeating CASE will cause me to repeat it up to 10 times, doesn't will it more complicated?

Comment: Then it seems using a nested query would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT 
    A.*,
    A.life * A.multiplier, 
    A.score * A.multiplier
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        CASE 
            WHEN extras.is_doubled THEN 2 
            WHEN extras.is_normal THEN 1 
            ELSE 0.5 
        END as multiplier, 
    FROM 
        table 
    inner join 
        ... 
    inner join 
        ...
    inner join
) A;
```

Comment: In your query extra.is_doubled will affect the sum of all row, but i want to use extra.is_doubled conditionally that will work only when A.life * A.multiplier, A.score * A.multiplier will within the sub-query, i suppose to. Also i want something else rather than this :(

Comment: @Mohammadyasin, I don't think this would be the case, because `multiplier` would e created per record basis, and the same would be multiplied to the `life` and `score` columns on per row basis.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of MySQL (8.0+) supports CTEs, then here's another way to do it:

```sql
WITH extras ( 
  SELECT life, score,
    CASE
      WHEN extras.is_doubled THEN 2 
      WHEN extras.is_normal 1 
      ELSE 0.5 
    END as multiplier
  FROM extras
)
SELECT 
  multiplier
  life * multiplier,
  score * multiplier
FROM extras
INNER JOIN ...
INNER JOIN ...
```